# How do I check if the clicked element is the same that had an onClick event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have the following code:

```
const checkParent = e => {
  console.log(e.target);
}

<Parent onClick={e => checkParent(e)}>
  <ChildOne>
  <ChildTwo>
</Parent>
```

How do I check if the clicked `e.target` is the `<Parent>` element, not one of its children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare `e.target` with `e.currentTarget`. The latter is the element that the handler is actually attached to. (That's not *literally* true in React because React uses delegated handlers, but React's synthetic event makes it seem so.)

So if `e.target === e.currentTarget`, it's the element the handler is "on."

Live Example:

```js
function ChildOne() {
    return <div>Child One</div>;
}
function ChildTwo() {
    return <div>Child Two</div>;
}
function Parent({children, onClick}) {
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}>
            Parent text
            {children}
            More parent text
        </div>
    );
}
function checkParent(e) {
    console.log(e.target === e.currentTarget ? "Yes" : "No");
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent onClick={e => checkParent(e)}>
        <ChildOne />
        <ChildTwo />
    </Parent>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, I tried to use `relatedTarget` assuming it's the same . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you attach ids you can test for them, e.g:

```
const checkParent = e => {
  const t = e.target;
  if (t.id === "child_one") { ... }
}

<Parent onClick={e => checkParent(e)}>
  <ChildOne id="child_one">
  <ChildTwo id="child_two">
</Parent>
```